# JQGrid: line breaks/newline in textarea in IE gets lost at postback

Tags: internet-explorer, post, jqgrid, textarea, newline

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with jquery for client functionality.

I have a jqgrid with a textarea in one of my columns. When I add some line breaks/empty lines between text fragments in the jqgrid textarea, these line breaks get lost at postback to the server. This only happens with IE, firefox goes fine. This also only happens with the jqgrid, a textarea outside the jqgrid will post fine.

I know there is the display linebreak issue in IE for textarea in jqgrid as well and it can get fixed by applying css 'white-space:pre-wrap' to it. But the issue I have is at postback.

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Thx for your help.